# Understanding iterators and zip in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iterator

Consider this `for` loop:

```
zipped = zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
for a, b in zipped:
    print(a, b)
```

This, as expected, returns:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

However, if I rerun the exact same code again but skipping the `zipped`definition (as it was already defined above), it returns nothing:

```
for a, b in zipped:
    print(a, b)
```

zipped is still the `zip` element that I created above, but it seems as if, after executing the `for`loop the first time, it lost its value. I would like to understand the logic behind all this.

Comment: Although see the last answer for the general "why".

Comment: Iterators are single-pass, after they've raised `StopIteration`, they must keep raising it after every invocation according to the iterator protocol